# Linq: how to group by, max and orderby

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

i have the following table:

```
id   serialcode    timestamp
1       0001       01/02/2015
2       0001       02/02/2015
3       0001       03/02/2015
4       0002       03/02/2015
```

In linq i want get the max id for a single (grouped by) serialcode. After, i want order the results for descending timestamp.

In this example, first, i want extract the following rows:

```
id   serialcode    timestamp
3       0001       03/02/2015
4       0002       03/02/2015
```

Then i'd like to order in descending timestamp.
How can achieve this in Linq?

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried anything ?

Comment: And if there are several rows with same id/max(serialcode) but different dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.Table.GroupBy(x => x.serialcode)
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.id).First())
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.timestamp);
```

Comment: I get issues with linq translating this when querying db.
I had to do `.Select(g => g.Max(x => x.Id))`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use ***Max()*** function:

```
var qry = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
        group r by r.Field<string>("serialcode") into grp
        select new {
            id = grp.Max(a=>a.Field<int>("id")),
            serialcode = grp.Key,
            timestamp = grp.Max(a=>a.Field<DateTime>("timestamp"))
        };
```

Result (as expected):

```
id    serialcode    timestamp
3    0001            2015-02-03 00:00:00 
4    0002            2015-02-03 00:00:00
```